# how to install rosserial package

Tags: ros, serial, communication

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ros hydro full desk top version. I have been trying to install the rosserial package, rosserial_xbee in particular, but failed. The error prompted in the terminal reads" unable to locate the package"? Does any have suggestions? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/126201/how-to-install-rosserial-package/) by [yading](https://answers.ros.org/users/11641/yading/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-04**:
What is the exact command that you're trying to run?

**Comment by [yading](https://answers.ros.org/users/11641/yading/) on 2014-02-05**:
Hi Ahendrix. The command I run was "sudo apt-get install rosserial_xbee".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosserial is not included in any desktop variant. You need to install it in addition to the default system, and the recommended way is to install one of the supported platforms (at this time that includes arduino and embedded_linux):

```
 sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosserial-arduino
```

In addition, the xbee package is not included with any of these, so:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-rosserial-xbee
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yading](https://answers.ros.org/users/11641/yading/) on 2014-02-05**:
Thank you Fergs! I run the two commands above and the problem was solved.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-05**:
Great! If you click on the checkmark next to my answer it will mark this as answered.